# After downloading all dependencies from package.json through maven ; Then automatically protractor test has to be triggered

Tags: maven, npm, jasmine, protractor, npm-install

Implementing on download all the dependencies through maven at run time then automatically `protractor conf.js` trigger so did the changes in POM.XML:

For downloading dependencies from package.json:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install (initialize)</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>


                    </configuration>
                        </execution>
</plugin>
```

For pointing to start protractor test:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.greengerong</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ng-protractor</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protractor>protractor</protractor>
                    <configFile>./conf.js</configFile>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ng-protractor</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>   
            </plugin>
```

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "protractor-html-reporter": "^1.3.2",
    "winston": "^2.3.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.1",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

When I run the pom.xml using `mvn clean install` node-modules folder created automatically which consist all dependencies but then `protractor conf.js` in not triggered .

How to automatically trigger protractor test after downloading all the dependencies ?

Comment: something must be missing in the conf.js . please attach your conf.js also ?

Comment: checking conf.js file and it's working fine if i didn't run through maven